# How I return a bearer access token from a controller in webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin, bearer-token

I am using the asp identity framework and I'm trying to use it with bearer tokens.

I would like to return an access token from the Register method in my webapi controller in the same format that is returned by the owin middleware when posting username/password details to the TokenEndpointPath.

All the examples I have seen relate to cookie based authentication, and they simply call AuthenticationManager.Signin(properties, identity) after the user has registered.

I would like to be able to return a response similar to the following:

```
{"access_token":"access-token","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1209599,"userName":"username",".issued":"Sat, 22 Mar 2014 08:12:14 GMT",".expires":"Sat, 05 Apr 2014 08:12:14 GMT"}
```

Do I have to create my own class and serialize all these fields myself when the functionality to this must already exist somewhere?

Comment: Please always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!  There were existing tags for the technologies you're using.

Comment: I want to do the same. Any progress you made?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't made any progress.. After spending far too long trying to work this out I just created my own class and serialized the values myself... I'm sure there would be a way to do it but I just don't know what it is! Hopefully someone will be able to help out with this at some point and I'll be able to remove this code

Comment: If understand you correctly I think it was answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969817/generate-token-in-controller